# Items in QHBoxLayout layout overlap

Tags: c++, qt, layout, qt5

I can't figure out what is wrong with Qt. I am trying to create a simple layout, like this:

```
+-------+-----------+
|       | Label1    |
| Thumb |-----------+
|       | Label2    |
|       |(multiline)|
+-------+-----------+
```

And this is the code that does this:

```
    labelInfoName = new QLabel("Sample name", this);
    labelInfoDetails = new QLabel("Sample details...", this);
    labelInfoDetails->setAlignment(static_cast<Qt::Alignment>(Qt::AlignTop | Qt::AlignLeft));

    QVBoxLayout* textInfoLayout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    textInfoLayout->addWidget(labelInfoName);
    textInfoLayout->addWidget(labelInfoDetails, 1);

    // Create info pane
    imgInfoThumbnail = new QLabel(this);
    imgInfoThumbnail->setFixedSize(64, 64);
    imgInfoThumbnail->setStyleSheet("background: black;");

    QHBoxLayout* infoLayout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
    infoLayout->addWidget(imgInfoThumbnail);
    infoLayout->addLayout(textInfoLayout, 1)

    this->setLayout(infoLayout);
```

And `this` is a `QWidget`. This is the code that sets up the layout in a class derived from `QWidget`. Then I want to display it as a dockable widget, which I do like this from my `QMainWindow` class:

```
    widget = new Widget(this); // Widget that was set up above
    QDockWidget* dockWidget = new QDockWidget("Project", this);
    dockWidget->setWidget(widget);
    addDockWidget(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea, dockWidget);
```

But this is what I get instead:

[image: what I get instead]

I need the widget to be a custom control that I can place anywhere. Previously, it was defined as a `QDockWidget`, and instead of calling `this->setLayout()` I was creating a `QWidget` object, and this worked as expected:

```
    QWidget* widget = new QWidget(this);
    widget->setLayout(infoLayout);
    this->setWidget(widget);
```

But the way I've done it now, it puts them on top of each other. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating layout incorrectly.

When you pass parent (widget) to a layout this layout is set automatically as layout to this widget.
Problem is that once layout is set for a widget it can't be changed, I'm pretty sure you are receiving some warning about this.

So just remove `this` when constructing a layout (at least in first case):

```
labelInfoName = new QLabel("Sample name", this);
labelInfoDetails = new QLabel("Sample details...", this);
labelInfoDetails->setAlignment(static_cast<Qt::Alignment>(Qt::AlignTop | Qt::AlignLeft));

QVBoxLayout* textInfoLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
textInfoLayout->addWidget(labelInfoName);
textInfoLayout->addWidget(labelInfoDetails, 1);

// Create info pane
imgInfoThumbnail = new QLabel(this);
imgInfoThumbnail->setFixedSize(64, 64);
imgInfoThumbnail->setStyleSheet("background: black;");

QHBoxLayout* infoLayout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
infoLayout->addWidget(imgInfoThumbnail);
infoLayout->addLayout(textInfoLayout, 1)

this->setLayout(infoLayout);
```

Comment: This was it, thank you. One more question: will Qt free all these allocated objects automatically, or do I have to delete them? I always thought that passing 'this' as the parent will make all these allocated objects be freed when 'this' was destroyed.

Comment: yes it will be freed. Simply layout have to have a parent widget (not necessary directly). When you assign a layout all items in it are reparented to respective widget. You can check `parent` value for widgets or `parentWidget` for layout all will point same as `this`.